# Where is PHP error log in CENTOS or set path for error log in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, logging, yii2, centos

I tried to look into

`/var/logs/apache2/error_log` it did not help me, following is the ending of my log, that does not get updated when i get error again and again

[image]

I tried to set `log_erros=on` and `error_log=/home/sami/php_errors.txt` in `php.ini` it gives nothing. I am working with yii framework, so I tried to put

```
    ini_set('log_errors', true);
    ini_set('error_log', '/home/sami/php_errors.txt');
```

in ErrorHandeler.register function, it still does not give anything

I have all the access to system but unable to produce/view error logs, have tried for more than 10 hours but unable to find any working solution yet, following is the error I am facing

[image]

Comment: Look up in `runtime/logs/app.log`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco That's the answer, thanks a lot, new has bee searching for error logs, and could not think to find logs